# Accessing markdown files with Vercel and Remix.run

Tags: vercel, remix.run

I'd like to know if it's possible to deploy a Remix.run project on Vercel that accesses markdown files. A project just like the [blog tutorial](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/blog);

```js
// posts.js
const postsPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "posts");
```

The warning says: "If you did not use the Remix App Server you'll probably need to add an extra ".." on the path. Also note that you can't deploy this demo anywhere that doesn't have a persistent file system.".

I tried with an extra "..". I thought Vecel could have a permanent file system with `"ENABLE_FILE_SYSTEM_API": "1"` but it's apparently not the case. Or is it?

Here is the Remix config:

```
module.exports = {
  appDirectory: 'app',
  assetsBuildDirectory: 'public/build',
  publicPath: '/build/',
  serverBuildDirectory: 'api/_build',
  ignoredRouteFiles: ['.*'],
  // mdx,
}
```

Comment: Can you post your remix config and folder structure for your code? Need to see where the  `..` goes to.

Comment: @TomasVancoillie I'm seeing the same thing: `/posts` are in the root folder, and not being included in the build, the code is in `/app` See https://github.com/jweatherby/jweatherby.dev

Comment: @TomasVancoillie I tried from the root `./posts.js`  or from `./app/posts.js`.
I tried to look into `..`, `../..`, `../../..`  etc. Could not find the source files from anywhere.

Just edited my posts with the remix config